# Combining images with Konva and use as new image?

Tags: konvajs

I made a spritesheet in Photoshop that contains about 100 tiles. I have 10 colors and 10 symbols and need each combination.

It would be a lot more flexible and easier if I could create these images in Konva by combining a color tile with a symbol imag. For speed reasons and the fact that I will already have lots of tiles on the screen, I don't want to use 2 `Konva.Image` shapes for this.

Is there any way in Konva to create the combined images and put them in some kind of buffer to re-use them ?

Comment: What do you want to have as a result on canvas? 100 `Konva.Image`s? Instead of 200?

Comment: Yep - the feature is called the Konva.Goup object. Create a group, add a rect as the tile background, add the symbol as the foreground, Then do all the movement activity on the group object. Alternatively, you can use the toDataURL() function to cache the groups as individual JS image objects and remove the groups. You could make a tile generator function to simplify this process. No guarantees on performance though - you would need to R&D to find the best performance for your use case. You might find the Konva,Group approach is faster because of the vector drawing of the tile background.